# How to avoid WARN messages about ReflectionsException

Tags: exception, log4j, warnings, confluent-platform

how can I avoid WARN messages to be displayed in logs (without putting the log4j level to ERROR) when I launch Confluent ?
I have set up my `plugin.path` variable in the properties file with value `${CONFLUENT_HOME}/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc` (with final comma).
I tried to put in the classpath the kafka-connect-jdbc repository, without success.

The following is just an example a small part of the log file:

```
[2018-07-10 15:40:30,168] INFO Reflections took 1 ms to scan 1 urls, producing 5 keys and 6 values [using 1 cores] (org.reflection
s.Reflections)
[2018-07-10 15:40:30,170] WARN could not get type for name org.jmock.Mockery from any class loader (org.reflections.Reflections)
org.reflections.ReflectionsException: could not get type for name org.jmock.Mockery
        at org.reflections.ReflectionUtils.forName(ReflectionUtils.java:390)
        at org.reflections.Reflections.expandSuperTypes(Reflections.java:381)
        at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:126)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader$InternalReflections.<init>(DelegatingClassLoader.java:
365)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanPluginPath(DelegatingClassLoader.java:277)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanUrlsAndAddPlugins(DelegatingClassLoader.java:216)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.registerPlugin(DelegatingClassLoader.java:208)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initPluginLoader(DelegatingClassLoader.java:177)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initLoaders(DelegatingClassLoader.java:154)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.<init>(Plugins.java:56)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jmock.Mockery
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at org.reflections.ReflectionUtils.forName(ReflectionUtils.java:388)
        ... 10 more
```

That does not seem causing any issues, but can be confusing to read about it. 
Have you got any suggestions about that ?

Thanks in advance,

Diego

Answer (score 1):

You can set log level for particular package in log4j config file:

```
log4j.logger.org.reflections=ERROR
```

This helped me